# Laravel PDF blank after using foreach loop for building items inside

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, pdf, laravel-blade

I use a stored procedure to send data to a pdf template, after that, I loop the JSON in a for-each to build the items inside the pdf, this procedure works fine in local, however, the pdf returns blank after I try this procedure in production on a remote server.

This is my method inside the controller to get my JSON and send it to the pdf.

```
    public function generarFichaPago(Request $request)
{
    $datosPDF = DB::select('exec SP_GenerarPDF @Op = ?, @matricula = ?, @ciclo = ?, @mes = ?', ['fichaPago', $request->matricula, $request->ciclo, $request->mes]);
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('Oficios.FichaPagoInsc', compact('datosPDF'))->setPaper('a4');
    $path = public_path('pdf/');
    $fileName =  time().'.'. 'pdf' ;
    $pdf->save($path . '/' . $fileName);
    $pdf = public_path('pdf/'.$fileName);
    return response()->download($pdf);
}
```

I call the method in the controller using ajax to create a blob and return a downloadable.

```
function generarReferencia(mes) {
var ciclo = document.getElementById("ciclo").value;
var matricula = document.getElementById("matricula").value;
console.log(ciclo,matricula,mes);

$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: '/pdf/fichaPago', 
    data: {
        "matricula": matricula,
        "ciclo": ciclo,
        "mes": mes,
    },
    xhrFields: { 
        responseType: 'blob' 
    }, 
    success: function(response){ 
        var blob = new Blob([response]); 
        var link = document.createElement('a'); 
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
        link.download = "Sample.pdf"; 
        link.click(); 
    }, 
    error: function(blob){ 
        console.log(blob); 
    } 
});
```

This is inside my PDF template where I want to show the data.

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($datosPDF as $dato)
    <div id="n1" class="cell">
        {{-- <img src="{{ asset('images/logo_bbva.jpg') }}" width="105" height="105"> --}}
        Num. CIE: XXXXXXXXXXX
    </div>
    <div id="n2" class="cell">
        <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
            <li>Alumno: <strong>{{$dato->MATRICULA}} {{$dato->NOMBRE_P}}</strong></li>
            <li>Ciclo Escolar: <strong>{{$dato->CICLO}}</strong></li>
            <li>Nivel: <strong>{{$dato->SECCION}}</strong></li>
            <li>Grado: <strong>{{$dato->GRADO}}°</strong></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="leyenda">
            <strong style="color: blue">Pago Inscripción Ciclo {{$dato->CICLO}}</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="n3" class="cell">
        <br>
        <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
            <li>Referencia: <strong>1234567890</strong></li>
            <li>Vigencia Al: <strong>{{$dato->FECHA_LIM}}</strong></li>
            <li>Importe: <strong>{{$dato->IMP_PAG}}</strong></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="n4" class="cell">
        <p>___________ FIRMA</p>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

This whole procedure works fine a generates the pdf correctly in local, like this. [image]

But when I try this on production in a remote server the pdf return blank, like this.[image]

I'm not sure what the error is in this instance, since the controller and template are identical, and the information inside the JSON is also the same, so both pdf should show the same info but one generates a blank pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the pdf looks fine in Chrome, both in local and in production servers, so the problem was with the Edge Browser not showing the PDF properly. I'm still not sure if this is related to a problem with the cache or a bug mentioned [in this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1319962/how-to-fix-edge-showing-empty-pdfs).

So the issue is solved but I guess I should change browsers in the meantime.